# Why is this sidebar data not going to ajax and why is slider value showing ui not defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a sidebar which contains some input. I want to get this data into my ajax. I am logging these inputs. However, I am not getting anything. Here is what I did:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $("#find_match").click(function() {
        alert("clicked");
    });
</script>

<aside>
    <br><br>
    Select Gender
    <select name="gender" id="gender">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
    </select>
            
    <hr>
    Educational Qualification : 
    <select class="form-control" name="eduQualification" id="eduQualification" class="required">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="10">10th</option>
        <option value="12">12th</option>
        <option value="15">Graduate</option>
        <option value="17">Post Graduate</option>
    </select>
            
    <hr>
    Salary expectation (in rupees):
    <select class="form-control" name="salary" id="salary">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">Upto 1 lakh</option>
        <option value="2">Upto 1-2 lakhs</option>
        <option value="3">2-5 lakh</option>
        <option value="4">5-10 lakh</option>
        <option value="5">More than 10 lakh</option>
    </select>

    <br><br>
    <button id="find_match">Search matches </button>
    </aside>
```

I am not getting any data in my console even when all my files are in place.
I have a slider which is in my html page and I want to get its value in jquery; for this it say "ui not defined".

Heres the snippet-

```
<label for="amount">Age range:</label>
                <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
                <div id="slider-range"></div>
```

js code-

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
          range: true,
          min: 20,
          max: 60,
          values: [ 20, 30 ],
          slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
          }
        });
        $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
          " - " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
        });
    </script>


    $("#find_match").click(function(){

  // I want to get the value of slider here..    
        var minAge = $('#amount').val(ui.values[ 0 ]);

});
```

I suppose.. it is giving that error because its not getting ui variable which comes as a part of callback in slide().
How to resolve this problem?
Please help.

Comment: put your click handler after the elements or in a dom ready state!

Comment: You don't have to do  `""+""`  in console.log. You can do: `console.log(var1, var2, var3)`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

As the comment above suggests, you need to wait for the `DOM` to be ready. If the `DOM` isn't ready you cannot bind an event handler to an element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#find_match").click(function(){
        alert("clicked");
    });
});
```

The second part of your question with the new JavaScript you posted is messed up. You need to put the event handler portion of your code within the `document.ready` function. This is what it should be:

```
$(function() {
    $("#slider-range").slider({
      range: true,
      min: 20,
      max: 60,
      values: [ 20, 30 ],
      slide: function(event, ui) {
          $("#amount").val(ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
      }
    });

    // Took this out of the val() and put it in a var so it's easier to read
    var sliderVal = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
        " - " + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1);
    $("#amount").val(sliderVal);

    // The code below must be within a document.ready, or the event
    // handler won't bind to the element because the DOM isn't ready!
    $("#find_match").click(function() {
        // I want to get the value of slider here..    
        var minAge = $('#amount').val(ui.values[ 0 ]);
    });
});
```

Comment: It worked like that. I had defined it individually thats why it was not working.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "defined it individually". Any code which is going to interact with the `DOM` in any way should be in a `$(document).ready()`, regardless of where in your application/HTML that code exists.

Comment: I mean it was $(document).ready().. I have updated my question slightly. Please check